# Listview scrolls in reverse after reaching the end?

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a `listview` in a `fragment` inside an `activity`. All the basic functionality is working totally fine. But there is strange behavior I've observed recently.
While scrolling really fast, as soon as the `listview` reaches either end, it starts scrolling in the reverse direction automatically. This behavior is not seen while scrolling slowly or while scrolling with the fast scrolling knob.
There are no errors or exceptions at all so I'm unable to find out the cause of such behavior.

Any help will be really appreciated.

Here is the `xml` definition of my `listview`:

```
<ListView
        android:id="@id/android:list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:divider="@null" >
    </ListView>
```

The implementaion in code is very basic and so I'm not posting it here but stil if it's needed, I'll post that too.

Comment: try changing the height of list view to match parent and tell if that issue still occurs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=159739) in Android, and *"will be fixed in a future release"*.
So unfortunately, it's not something you can solve for your application.

Comment: Oh is it? I didn't know that. It's strange I couldn't find anything like that on google. Must have missed some place! Well, I believe I need not worry about it then. Thanks. Anyway, is there a way you know of to get around this bug?

Comment: It took me a while to find this issue as well. You should be able to see the same behavior in some of the 'larger' applications, like Spotify and the Contacts application, though I cannot reproduce it in the M preview image. I haven't heard of some sort of workaround for this.